# Modify adapter to set multiple textviews in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom adapter that creates groups within a listview. I now want to change it so the elements within the groups will have more than just the one line of text. Here is my adapter

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
private TreeSet<Integer> sectionHeader = new TreeSet<Integer>();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSectionHeaderItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    sectionHeader.add(mData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return sectionHeader.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item1, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item2, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

}

and the xml for the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView android:id="@id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/text"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd change it to accept an ArrayList>() instead of ArrayList() but I'm not sure how to get it to set both lines of text. I'll do something similar for the header as well once I get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I figured this out. In the switch add this

```
case TYPE_ITEM:
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_item1, null);
holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
holder.textView2.setText("test");
break;
```

To get the other text view. Then add the text view to the viewholder, like so

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public TextView textView2;
}
```

I had to move the holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position)); into the switch because it doesn't exist on the header thus causing a fatal error. From here I just have to change what it accepts for items and parse them appropriately.